# Building and using a newer GLIBC on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, glibc

I use CentOS 7 and would like to use some Anaconda python package that requires GLIBC_2.18 while the host OS only provides 2.17. I tried compiling a newer version of glibc myself following these [instructions](https://gist.github.com/carlesloriente/ab3387e7d035ed400dc2816873e9089e). When I try to run any executable with this newer glibc I am getting an error:

```sh
$ ./testrun.sh ls
ls: error while loading shared libraries: ls: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

**Update 1:**

As per suggestion in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68698298/714011) I needed to specify the full path to the executable, which now gives a different error message:

```sh
$ cd glibc-2.20/build # build directory
$ ./testrun.sh /bin/ls
/bin/ls: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Update 2:**

Adding paths to the system libraries in `testrun.sh` solved the problem. I can not only run `ls` but also the aforementioned python package. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of rebuilding newer glibc, you should rebuild the python package.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried building this package before, but it has tremendously many dependencies and at one point it failed and I couldn't proceed further. So I wanted to try a simpler solution.

Comment: Use a different distro or an older version of that package. Otherwise you'll find yourself in a world of pain.

Comment: I'd love to use Ubuntu/Debian, but unfortunately I am stuck with CentOS which is what they use at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `./testrun.sh /bin/ls`.

That said, you will really be better off building the Python package for your system, instead of trying to make non-system GLIBC, as Danila Vershinin suggested.

**Update:**

> `libselinux.so.1: ...: No such file or directory`

The `testrun.sh` for the new GLIBC does not look in system directories (e.g. `/usr/lib64`). You need to *append* system directories to the `--library-path` it uses. E.g. change

```
--library-path "${builddir}":"${builddir}"/math:"${builddir}"/elf:"${builddir}"/dlfcn:"${builddir}"/nss:"${builddir}"/nis:"${builddir}"/rt:"${builddir}"/resolv:"${builddir}"/mathvec:"${builddir}"/support:"${builddir}"/crypt:"${builddir}"/nptl
```

to:

```
--library-path "${builddir}":"${builddir}"/math:"${builddir}"/elf:"${builddir}"/dlfcn:"${builddir}"/nss:"${builddir}"/nis:"${builddir}"/rt:"${builddir}"/resolv:"${builddir}"/mathvec:"${builddir}"/support:"${builddir}"/crypt:"${builddir}"/nptl:/usr/lib64:/lib64
```

(or something like that).

Comment: @SimpleMan That's hard to believe. Can you edit the question to show the _exact_ command line you typed and _exact_ error this command produced? Also, I assume that `/bin/ls` is the `ls` you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question, running `/bin/ls` indeed changed the error message, now it complains about not finding `libselinux.so.1`.

Comment: @SimpleMan Please don't remove parts of your question (as it stands, this answer makes no sense). Append to it (as I have done).

Comment: You rock, this has solved the problem and I can at last run the python package I long wanted to! Also thanks for the tips on how to use this site, I updated the original question to preserve the timeline of the discussion.